# Neural networks for generation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Okay so - I've been messing around with neural networks in python and I've made a few feed forward ones and a few recurrent ones. I know how they work on a pretty basic level.

Sometimes I'll see people who are using neural networks to generate things like text, for example; they'll claim to have trained it on a few thousand paragraphs and then it'll write a new paragraph. I read an article recently about a neural network that analyzed thousands of fonts and then created its own font.

Here's the problem - all of the neural networks i've made so far take a dataset of inputs and outputs. These neural networks i'm reading about seem like they don't take input, they just look at many instances of something and then create a new instance of that (like they only deal with outputs).

Am I missing something? Are these neural networks I'm reading about a different type of neural network? Let's say I have a bunch of melodies in a format the neural network could handle (very short MIDI files). What type of network would I need to use to train it on this set of melodies and have it generate a new melody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done so far is probably what is called *classification*; What you want to look at now is *prediction* and *regression*.

You still train your network in the same way. 
Once trained, you still feed it an input, but instead of getting a category (from classification), you get a prediction of what will likely be the next step in a series. Eg. a series of notes. 
You still need to feed it input to work on. But i guess this could be random, semi-random, or maybe even generated notes.

Theres a good old short tutorial about prediction with neural nets here:
 http://www.obitko.com/tutorials/neural-network-prediction/

And then, look at the programming libraries you already use, and look for prediction or regression methods.

Comment: Thank you! You're right -- classification is what i've been doing, I'm looking into prediction and regression and it's exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, those are neural networks and for you sample application (music generation) you could easily use Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) or most robust version (such as LSTM) of RNN.

Following is a really nice article and I hope it will help you to understand how you could build those generative models.

[The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/)

In fact, people have done music generations using RNN and following GitHub location is one of such examples.

[Biaxial Recurrent Neural Network for Music Composition](https://github.com/hexahedria/biaxial-rnn-music-composition)

If you want to dive deep into the neural network and learn more about the state of art theories/applications, I would like to suggest following books (both are freely available).

1. [Neural Networks and Deep](http://Learninghttp://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/)
2. [Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/)

**EDIT:**
The following site has some online demos as well

[Composing Music With Recurrent Neural Networks](http://www.hexahedria.com/2015/08/03/composing-music-with-recurrent-neural-networks/)